# open sikuli-ide from terminal failed

Tags: sikuli

hello i was working on ubuntu 13.10 and i update it to 14.04 but now when i want to open                  sikuli from terminal to run python i get an error like this:

```
developer@developers:~$ sikuli-ide
[info] locale: en_US
Exceptioninthread"main"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/google/common/collect/MapMaker
at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:1280)
at org.python.core.PyObject.<init>(PyObject.java:66)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinCallable.<init>(PyBuiltinCallable.java:21)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethod.<init>(PyBuiltinMethod.java:16)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.<init>(PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.java:24)
at org.python.core.PyType$type___subclasses___exposer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyType$PyExposer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyType.<clinit>(PyType.java)
at org.python.core.PyObject.<init>(PyObject.java:66)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinCallable.<init>(PyBuiltinCallable.java:21)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethod.<init>(PyBuiltinMethod.java:16)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.<init>(PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.java:24)
at org.python.core.PyDataDescr$getset_descriptor___get___exposer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyDataDescr$PyExposer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyDataDescr.<clinit>(PyDataDescr.java)`enter code here`
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinCallable$PyExposer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinCallable.<clinit>(PyBuiltinCallable.java)
at org.python.core.PyObject$PyExposer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyObject.<clinit>(PyObject.java)
at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.initialize(PythonInterpreter.java:57)
at org.sikuli.script.ScriptRunner.init(ScriptRunner.java:32)
at org.sikuli.script.ScriptRunner.<init>(ScriptRunner.java:28)
at org.sikuli.script.ScriptRunner.getInstance(ScriptRunner.java:23)
at org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE.<init>(SikuliIDE.java:664)
at org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE.getInstance(SikuliIDE.java:138)
at org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE.main(SikuliIDE.java:975)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.MapMaker
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 26 more
```

does someone can help thanks

Comment: I got the same problem